# Getting "Assertion failure" in UISearchResultsTableView

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm getting the following error when i start type the search text in SearchBar

```
Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]
```

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code for `Search Display Controller` is as follows :

```
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [search objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your code with this one may be it will work.

```
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [search objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

because once you find that the cell object is nil again you are allocating the cell with nil object using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` that's why it is not working.

Comment: What if I want to use custom Cell?

Comment: I dont have a Custom XIB file differently

Comment: you can also follow the tutorial on these links http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/  or  http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/  it will explain you the full process.

Comment: if you are using storyboard you do not need to create a separate xib for your cell but can crete it inside the table only and also do not need to register it programatically.

Comment: now if you have created the nib inside the table view then just give it a CellIdentifier and use it inside the cellforrowatindexpath as CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; also create a CustomCell as subclass of UITableViewCell and set your prototype cell parent class as Your CustomClass

Comment: You can also find a good tutorial regarding use of custom cell using storyboard on http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/